# mvc images in_Layout.cshtml missing in some of my views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my **_Layout.cshtml**, I have the main section for the views as shown below:

```html
<div class="right_col" role="main" style="color: black; background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');background-repeat:repeat">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
```

It properly set background image for create views.For Example **CADCreate.cshtml**
But misses the backrground image for edit and delete views. For example **CADEdit.cshtml** and **CADDelete.cshtml**.

**Note :**

- All views mentioned above, **except Layout.cshtml**, are in the same folder.
- The images folder is under my project folder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK! if any body face this situation, what worked for me finally was replacing the image url like this:

```html
<div class="right_col" role="main" style="color: black; background-image: url('/images/bg.jpg');background-repeat:repeat">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
```

the **'/'** before images/bg.jpg tells the path to start from the project root folder.